# C++: How can I stop map's operator[] from inserting bogus values?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

My code did the following:

1. Retrieve a value from a `map` with `operator[]`.
2. Check the return value and if `NULL` use `insert` to insert a new element in the map.

Magically, an element with value `0` appeared in the map.

After several hours of debugging I discovered the following: `map`'s `operator[]` [inserts a new element if the key is not found](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/operator%5B%5D/) while `insert` [does not change the value if the key exists](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/insert/).

Even if a default constructor for the map value type does not exist the code compiles and `operator[]` inserts `0`.

Is there a way (e.g. some coding convention I could follow from now on) I could have prevented this from hurting me?

Comment: So what should `operator[]` return if it fails to find an element?

Comment: The related question: [STL MAP should use find() or \[n\] identifier to find element in map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582089/stl-map-should-use-find-or-n-identifier-to-find-element-in-map); it has some useful answers.

Comment: Several hours of debugging: $1500. Reading the [free manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at): priceless.

Comment: @KerrekSB, where can I get $1500 for several hours of debugging? I think I should switch positions. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way (e.g. some coding convention I could follow from now on) I could have prevented this from hurting me?

This may sound snarky, but: by reading the documentation.

Since what you did is somewhat *expected* behaviour of the map, there’s not much you can do to guard against it.

One thing you *can* heed in the future is the following. In your second step, you did something wrong:

> Check the return value and if NULL use insert to insert a new element in the map.

This does **never** work with C++ standard library functions (other than C compatibility functions and `new`): the standard library doesn’t deal in pointers, least of all null pointers, so checking against `NULL` (or `0` or `nullptr`) rarely makes sense. (Apart from that, it wouldn’t make sense for a map’s `operator []` to return a pointer in the first place. It *obvoiusly* returns the *element type* (or rather, a reference to it)).

In fact, the standard library predominantly uses *iterators* so if at all, check for iterator validity by comparing against the `end()` of a container.

Unfortunately, your code (checking against `NULL`) compiled since `NULL` is actually a macro that’s equal to `0` in C++ so you can compare it against an integer.

C++11 gets safer by introducing the `nullptr` keyword which has a distinct type, so comparing it with an integer wouldn’t compile. So this is a useful coding convention: never use `NULL`, and instead compile with C++11 support enabled and use `nullptr`.

Answer (score 7):

I guess the obvious is to learn that those are indeed the semantics of the indexing operator, so you should not use it to test for element existance in a container.

Instead, use `find()`.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, when you call `operator []`, if a value at that key is not found, a **value-initialized** default value is inserted.

If you don't want this to happen, you have to check with `find`:

```
if ( mymap.find(myKey) == mymap.end() )
{
    //the key doesn't exist in a map
}
```

The value returned by `operator []` will be `NULL` only if it's a map to pointers (or types that value-initialized yield 0, but you were pretty specific about `NULL`).

Answer (score 4):

> Even if a default constructor for the map value type does not exist
>   the code compiles

This is definitely wrong. `operator[]` should fail to compile if a default constructor does not exist. Anything else is an error on the part of your implementation.

Your code should have simply used `insert` once.

Answer (score 2):

Latest implementations of std::map also have a `.at(const Key& key)` member functions which checks for existence of value and returns a `std::out_of_range` exception if the key has not been found.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the [] operator, call find on your map. This will not insert an entry if no match is found. It returns an iterator to the item found.

Answer (score 0):

Here are several examples of map lookup and insert use cases, where you sometimes want to handle the case of items already existing, seeing what old value was, etc.

```
class Foo
{
    // Use a typedef so we can conveniently declare iterators
    // and conveniently construct insert pairs
    typedef map<int, std::string> IdMap;
    IdMap id_map;

    // A function that looks up a value without adding anything
    void one(int id)
    {
        IdMap::iterator i = id_map.find(id);

        // See if an entry already exists
        if (i == id_map.end())
            return; // value does not exist

        // Pass the string value that was stored in the map to baz
        baz(i->second);
    }

    // A function that updates an existing value, but only if it already exists
    bool two(int id, const std::string &data)
    {
        IdMap::iterator i = id_map.find(id);

        if (i == id_map.end())
            return false;

        i->second = data;
        return true;
    }

    // A function that inserts a value only if it does NOT already exist
    // Returns true if the insertion happened, returns false if no effect
    bool three(int id, const std::string &data)
    {
        return id_map.insert(IdMap::value_type(id, data)).second;
    }

    // A function that tries to insert if key doesn't already exist,
    // but if it does already exist, needs to get the current value
    void four(int id, const std::string &data)
    {
        std::pair<IdMap::iterator,bool> i =
            id_map.insert(IdMap::value_type(id, data));

        // Insertion worked, don't need to process old value
        if (i->second)
            return true;

        // Pass the id to some imaginary function that needs
        // to know id and wants to see the old string and new string
        report_conflict(id, i->first->second, data);
    }
};
```

Programmers often do multiple redundant calls to `operator[]`, or a call to `find` then a redundant call to `operator[]`, or a call to `find` then a redundant call to `insert`, out of laziness or ignorance. It is quite easy to efficiently use a map if you understand its semantics.

Answer (score 0):

operator[] actually returns a Value& so if you are sure you want to insert the element you can do something like:

```
map<Key, Value*> my_map;

Value& entry = my_map[key];  // insert occurs here, using default constructor.
if (entry == nullptr) entry = my_new_entry;  // just changing the value
```

Added benefit is that you only lookup in the map once.