# Editing the value in an unordered map for a given key

Tags: c++, unordered-map, emplace

The following is C++ code to get a count of the words in magazine. I'm trying to add the word if its value does not exist and if it does, increment it.

```
unordered_map<string,int>hash;
vector<string> magazine(m);

for(int i = 0;i <m;i++)
{
   cin >> magazine[i];
   if(hash[magazine[i]]>0)
       hash[magazine[i]]++;
   else
    hash.emplace(magazine[i],1);
}
```

But when I try to output, all magazine key gives 0 as value. Any idea why?

Comment: `if(hash[magazine[i]]>0)` what do you thing that does?

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.  Your debugger is the right tool to answer this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your version doesn't work because this `if(hash[magazine[i]]>0)` will insert an element into `hash` if it doesn't exist, this new element will have a mapped value of `0`¹. Which means that `hash.emplace(magazine[i],1);` is pointless here because there will *always* be an element at `magazine[i]` now. Because its value will be `0` your `hash[magazine[i]]++;` will never run either because the `if` will never be `true`. Leaving you with a map of `i` elements, all with value `0`.

[`operator[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/operator[]/) returns a reference to the mapped value if there is one, if not, it inserts one and then returns that reference¹.

Which means that you can factor out the `if` and just change it to:

```
for(int i = 0;i <m;i++)
{
   cin >> magazine[i];
   ++hash[magazine[i]];
}
```

Which basically means : "*Get a reference to the mapped value for key `magazine[i]`, if none is found, insert one and give me that one. Increment this reference.*"

¹: <sub>If insertion occurs the element is value-initialized. Because your mapped value type is `int` this will result into the mapped value being `0` after insertion.</sub>

Comment: Please add to the answer that the newly created value is default initialized which means it holds a value of 0 for numeric types.

Comment: This works, but you haven't explained why the previous version didn't work (which is what the OP actually asked).

Comment: @Leon It is *value* initialized, which means it holds a value of 0 for numeric types. Default initialization of numeric types doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You are inadvertently creating a new element in the map by doing :

```
if(hash[magazine[i]]>0)
```

`map<>::operator[]` does insertion, value initialization(*that value is zero in your case*), and then returns the reference of value, *all very discreetly.*

As correctly suggested in many comments, the best way is:

```
hash[key]++
```

[Read more.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582089/stl-map-should-use-find-or-n-identifier-to-find-element-in-map)

Answer (score 1):

`if(hash[magazine[i]]>0)` creates **new** item if the key is not exist.

What you really want is:

```
if(hash.find(magazine[i])!=hash.end())
```

As @juanchopanza mentioned, you do not need the branching. `std::unordered_map::operator []` can handle it like this:

```
hash[magazine[i]]++;
```

Comment: No, they don't need any conditionals. Just `hash[magazine[i]]++;`.

Comment: Or remove the `if` entirely, and *just* use `hash[magazine[i]]++;`.  The element will be created with value 0 if necessary, and then incremented.  This *is* the use-case for indexing into a map creating an element if it doesn't exist - I still thing it was the wrong decision though.

Comment: @juanchopanza You mean that it defaulted with 0 and ++ is responsible to make it 1 ? even so, the OP needs a clarification about what is happening and what is the exact alternative IMO

Comment: Not really, `hash[magazine[i]]++;` is always the answer here.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Yes, good to point out what is wrong. I tried to get them to figure it out by asking a question in the comments.

Comment: I think you need to point out that .emplace will do nothing if the element already exists (and the test ensures it does) - thus the element will remain zero, and the next time round the loop, the same thing will happen.

Comment: @juanchopanza @Martin @GillBates `hash[magazine[i]]++;` doesn't answer the question that was asked by `OP`. It is (possibly) a useful comment to add to the answer .

Comment: @Galik: Agreed.  Hence my comment about emplace doing nothing because the element exists.